# JavaScript - After inheriting Array the filter function becomes broken

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I think I have found a bug in [zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/0cd020f2d22be04119210acd2455c52c410aa26d/src/pipeline.js#L55).

This code works:

```
function twoArguments(a, b) { }

function threeArguments(a, b, c) { }

let pipeline = new Array();
pipeline.push(twoArguments);
pipeline.push(threeArguments);

let onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs = pipeline.filter(fn => fn.length === 2);
console.log(onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs);
```

But following code doesn't filter out non-two arguments functions:

```
class Pipeline extends Array {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.push(twoArguments);
        this.push(threeArguments);
    }

    run() {
        return this.filter(fn => fn.length === 2);
    }

}

let pipeline = new Pipeline();
let onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs = pipeline.run();
console.log(onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs);
```

Still returns both of functions. Please explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `Symbol.species` to original `Array` constructor fixes this

```
class Pipeline extends Array {
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }

    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**:
`Array.prototype.filter` implementation does not mutate the original object, instead it creates a new one to store the result in. In this case, a derived constructor is used for this, which populates the object with exactly 2 values on every init.

You can set `Symbol.species` on the derived class to specifically tell `filter` to use the original `Array` constructor. Or you can remove initialization from the class, and use `new Pipeline(twoArguments, threeArguments)` or `Pipeline.of(…)`, as @Bergi suggests.

Comment: Care to explain why it fixes it?

Comment: My guess is that native `filter` implementation uses derived constructor, which always inits with 2 values.

Comment: Indeed, if you remove `this.push` instructions from constructor, and use the same init code as for `Array` example, it works without overriding `Symbol.species`.

Comment: @eur00t I think removing `push` from the constructor is the proper solution. Can you include that in your answer please? If you just omit the constructor, it should be possible to construct `const pipeline = new Pipeline(twoArguments, threeArguments);` or using `Pipeline.of(…)`

Comment: @Bergi included in EDIT

Comment: Another solution could be is to add `Array.prototype.filter` [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) into `Pipeline` class, but disadvantage is that it will only affect `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prototyping new methods, simply variable with function say fat arrow `=>` functions of es6 worked here

```
run = () => {
```

```js
function twoArguments(a, b) { }

function threeArguments(a, b, c) { }


class Pipeline extends Array {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.push(twoArguments);
        this.push(threeArguments);
    }

    run = () => {
        return this.filter(fn => fn.length === 2);
    }

}

let pipeline = new Pipeline();
let onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs = pipeline.run();
console.log(onlyTwoArgumentsFuncs);
```

Comment: @Bergi But It's giving the filtered array?

Comment: No, it's giving the filtered pipeline.

Comment: Yeah That's what OP asked. Instead of filtering, it's giving all array for OP. But this example giving the filtered one!.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is not Javascript code: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: @happy_marmoset you need to have `babel` to compile this `es6` standard code.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja, sorry, yes seems it is working somehow, but I can not understand why. Some dark magic of babel.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to create `Array` explicitly before performing filtering:

```
run() {
    return [].concat(this).filter(fn => fn.length === 2);
}
```